# How can I cut object in half in a straight cut so the two sides can be seperated for printing

Tags: modeling, knife-tool, loop

After creating this vulcano and sculpting it, I have to cut it in half because the 3D printer isn't big enough for my design. In total I will have to do two cuts to get 4 pieces.

How can I cut this object in a straight line along the x and y axis so that I can take them apart? (be aware that it is a hollow object as you can see in the picture)

[image: view from above]
[image: side view]
[image: hollow bottom]

Comment: loop cut? (this is dumb I'm new to blender sorry)

Comment: Sorry that does not help me. I've tried that but either I did it wrong or it doesn't work because of this object. I'd apreciate a step by step or a video solving my problem;)

Comment: Yess thank you! Follow-up question: Do you know how I can create a knob&recess or  some kind of puzzle-like-thing between the 4 pieces so that it can be put together and taken apart after printing?

Comment: For a follow-up question make a new question ;)

Comment: Use a Boolean modifier?